# Remove Space from flex column based on no of digits?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table using Flex. It has three columns. The number of digits determines the size of each column. If a column only has a single digit, that column must take up the space that corresponds to that. Please see the sample code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="align-item">1234</div>
   <div class="align-item">6</div>
   <div class="align-item">6</div>
</div>

.main-container {
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex: 1 1;
}
.align-item {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    margin-left: 0.3rem;
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

Note : Main-container is repeating to create no of rows.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this with flex, you would need to use column elements to wrap the cells and keep them aligned. Like so:

```css
.table {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">1234</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">51252</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">62</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">3354</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This could create complexities depending on how you are inserting the data.

[Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) might be more suited to this use case for simplicity, See example below:

```css
.table {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">1234555</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">51252</div>
  <div class="cell">36</div>
  <div class="cell">566</div>
  <div class="cell">1234</div>
  <div class="cell">36</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">1234</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks jack for the solution, there is one problem here <div class ="main-container"></div> is dynamically repeating.

Comment: No worries! If you can't alter the HTML structure for this then you might struggle to get the desired result with CSS alone since column widths will be different within each `main-container` since they don't have any reference to one another.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. even i have achieved alignment but the problem is its taking more space(even if all value of column is 0).